# Displaying the modal from the controller angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am new to angular js and am trying to create a simple modal using angular js. The following is my code for the modal

```
<div id="sampleModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Sample Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <h5>Name</h5>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter a name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div style="text-align:center;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button> 
              </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the above modal is invoked on clicking the following button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="modal" ng-click="create()">Create</button>
```

and my controller is as follows

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', []);
App.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope,) {
        $scope.create = function() {

         //code to show the modal
    }
    }]);
```

How should i write my create function in order to display the modal. I have seen many tutorials but couldn't find a way to get that working.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Angular UI Bootstrap. It has excellent modal support and an example to help you out.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Directly open modal not interact with controller.

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sampleModal">Create
    </button>
```

Step 2: Interact with controller.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="create()">Create</button>

var App = angular.module('myApp', []); App.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope,) {
        $scope.create = function() {

         angular.element('#sampleModal').modal('show');
    }

}]);
```

N.B: Modal should be `bootstrap`. and `Jquery` must be load in project.

Comment: I tried the answer that you have suggested, Its giving me Error: jqLite:nosel error.

Comment: Have your project include Jquery?? ...if not then inject it and try

Comment: Yeah i got it include Jquery above in angular script then try , i try my PC except Jquery and  it shows your ( Error: jqLite:nosel) . So inject Jquery                                                                                                   <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

Comment: Is there a way to include these js files without bower? I have a problem with installing bower

Comment: Yeah it's possible, download jquery then set path or you can use jquery cdnfy ...